# Guice: Injecting map binding with @Named

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I would like to have the following injection model. Is this possible with Guice?

### Module:

```
protected void configure() {
    MapBinder<String, IService> mapBinder = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, IService.class);
    mapBinder.addBinding("keyA").to(IServiceA.class);
    mapBinder.addBinding("keyB").to(IserviceB.class);
}
```

Class:

```
class SomeClass {
    private final IService service;

    @Inject
    SomeClass(@Named("KeyA") final IService serviceInstance) {
        this.service = serviceInstance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not what map binder are intended for.
In your example a binding annotation would be the way to go:
https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations

```
protected void configure() {
    bind(IServiceA.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("keyA"));
    bind(IServiceB.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("keyB"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `@Named` annotation has to add on the parameter of the method.

```
class SomeClass {
    private final IService service;

    @Inject
    SomeClass(@Named("KeyA") final IService serviceInstance) {
        this.service = serviceInstance;
    }
}
```

https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections#method-injection

Comment: OOPs. My wrong. Wrote that by mistake. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: Even so, this will not cause `MapBinder` and `@Named` keys to magically become compatible.